# Just get a boolean result from "if let"?

Tags: rust

Is there a more concise way to write this?

```
   let neg = if let Some(b'-') = self.peek() {
        true
   } else {
        false
   };
```

Where peek() returns an `Option<u8>`, if it wasn't clear from the code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Option [derives an implementation for Eq](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/option.rs.html#153), you can simply write:

```rust
let neg = Some(b'-') == self.peek();
```

Answer (score 4):

The other answer is accurate for the specific example because of `Eq`, but I'll answer in the general case.

Rust now has a [`matches!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/macro.matches.html) macro for this usecase, so you can also write

```
let neg = matches!(self.peek(), Some(b'-'));
```

if you don't want to or are unable to use `Eq`.